# Set DefaultValue in Access form to last record of a table

Tags: vba, ms-access, dlookup

I have an Access form with a text box named Box1.

In this text box, I want to have the **name** of the last product in my table **Products** as the default value.

My table product has the fields: *P_ID* and *P_Name*.

I have coded in VBA in the form:

```
Me!Box1.DefaultValue = DLookup("P_Name", "Products", "P_ID = DMax("P_ID", "Products")")
```

However, there is an error in my code as the textbox displays *#Name*.

Comment: Try `=DLookUp("P_Name","Products","P_ID = " & DMax("P_ID","Products"))`

Comment: i tried and my text box says #Name ? :(

Comment: Make sure you copied it correctly, it's working on mine.

Comment: Very weird. I copied your exact words and it doesn't work. I still get the #Name? error in my text box.

Answer (score 0):

The *DefaultValue* property is a string, so *quotes* are needed:

```
Me!Box1.DefaultValue = "'" & DLookup("P_Name", "Products", "P_ID = " & DMax("P_ID", "Products") & "") & "'"
```